# Get a part of a string that comes before "_"

Tags: swift

I want to get only the ID that comes before the first "_" but after several attempts I can't do it

String example:

```
"https://urlexample.com/EXAMPLE_STRING/video/multimedia/20219/27/2022492719125378_1664299242_video_1296.mp4"
```

The result should be:

```
"2022492719125378"
```

Right now I have this but I don't know how to make it only take the first numbers before the first "_"

```
var str = "https://urlexample.com/EXAMPLE_STRING/video/multimedia/20219/27/2022492719125378_1664299242_video_1296.mp4"

    // file name with extension
    let fileName = string.lastPathComponent
    print(fileName) // "2022092719125378_1664299242_video_1296.mp4" 

    // file id
    let fileId = string.deletingPathExtension.lastPathComponent
    print(fileId) // "2022092719125378_1664299242_video_1296"
```

If anyone can help I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `components(separatedBy:)` or `split(separator:)`. Both works the same if only one character.

```swift
let fileId = "2022092719125378_1664299242_video_1296"
let sliptArr = fileId.components(separatedBy: "_")
print(sliptArr[0]) // 2022092719125378
```

```swift
let fileId = "2022092719125378_1664299242_video_1296"
let sliptArr = fileId.split(separator: "_")
print(sliptArr[0]) // 2022092719125378
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let str = "https://urlexample.com/EXAMPLE_STRING/video/multimedia/20219/27/2022492719125378_1664299242_video_1296.mp4"

let fieldId = str.components(separatedBy: "/").last?.components(separatedBy: "_").first

print(fieldId)
```